# Rename ReturnUrl literal in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I put the authentication attribute that sets:

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

so when I try to access

```
http://www.mysite.com/Forum/Polls
```

and I am not authenticated I am redirected to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Account/Log?ReturnUrl=%2FForum%2FPolls
```

I want to have the following line instead:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Account/Log?back=%2FForum%2FPolls
```

, so instead of 'ReturnUrl' need 'back'. Where I can ovveride this behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone finds this in a search, I just submitted a request to have this fixed in a future .NET release. If you too would like MS to take notice then vote it up, pass it on, etc. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3049874-make-returnurl-a-configurable-key-name-instead-o

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite "ReturnURL" on EndRequest event.

This is sample code.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
  if (Response.StatusCode != 301 && Response.StatusCode != 302) return;

  var targetUrl = Response.RedirectLocation.Replace("ReturnUrl","back");
  Response.RedirectLocation = targetUrl;
}
```

Hope this code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can.  That comes from `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetLoginPage()`
If you look at the code, you see that it is indeed a hard coded literal.  At least in System.Web version 2.0.0.0